# Parsing huge JSON object for facebook post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

I am currently building an angular.js social media platform and am trying to display facebook posts on my feeds page for facebook.  I currently have this:

```
<div id='fb-root'>
    <div ng-repeat="post in facebook">
        Test: {{post}}
    </div>
</div>
```

which returns my Test post as:

[{"id":"4681211244366_4681199684077","from":{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones"},"story":"Zachy Bear Jones and Alexander J. Marrs are now friends.","story_tags":{"0":[{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones","offset":0,"length":16,"type":"user"}],"21":[{"id":"10205311345929912","name":"Alexander J. Marrs","offset":21,"length":18,"type":"user"}]},"actions":[{"name":"Comment","link":"https://www.facebook.com/4681211244366/posts/4681199684077"},{"name":"Like","link":"https://www.facebook.com/4681211244366/posts/4681199684077"}],"privacy":{"value":""},"type":"status","status_type":"approved_friend","created_time":"2014-10-11T21:33:29+0000","updated_time":"2014-10-11T21:33:29+0000"},{"id":"4681211244366_4678763463173pmpmymife","from":{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones"},"story":"Zachy Bear Jones commented on a status.","story_tags":{"0":[{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones","offset":0,"length":16,"type":"user"}]},"privacy":{"value":""},"type":"status","application":{"name":"Facebook for iPhone","namespace":"fbiphone","id":"6628568379"},"created_time":"2014-10-11T08:20:12+0000","updated_time":"2014-10-11T08:20:12+0000"},{"id":"4681211244366_4676849935336","from":{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones"},"story":"Zachy Bear Jones likes a photo.","story_tags":{"0":[{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones","offset":0,"length":16,"type":"user"}]},"privacy":{"value":""},"type":"status","created_time":"2014-10-10T18:35:16+0000","updated_time":"2014-10-10T18:35:16+0000"},{"id":"4681211244366_4676161038114","from":{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones"},"story":"Zachy Bear Jones likes The ManKind Project.","story_tags":{"0":[{"id":"4681211244366","name":"Zachy Bear Jones","offset":0,"length":16,"type":"user"}],"23":[{"id":"95845568627","name":"The ManKind Project","offset":23,"length":19,"type":"page"}]},"picture":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/v/t1.0-1/c25.37.310.310/s100x100/47037_10151832647868628_1954427594_n.png?

Back as my JSON object.  What is the next step to rendering this information as a post?  In a prefect world I need profile pic, message, time, location, and the like, share, and comment actions.  Any advice on how I can do this?  Thank you anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should format your json object to a readable one to get the certain structure. Based upon your object I did this as an example:

```
[{
    "id":"4681211244366_4681199684077",
    "from":{
        "id":"4681211244366",
        "name":"Zachy Bear Jones"
    },
    "story":"Zachy Bear Jones and Alexander J. Marrs are now friends.",
    "story_tags":{
        "0": [{
            "id":"4681211244366",
            "name":"Zachy Bear Jones",
            "offset":0,
            "length":16,
            "type":"user"
        }],
        "21":[{
            "id":"10205311345929912",
            "name":"Alexander J. Marrs",
            "offset":21,
            "length":18,
            "type":"user"
        }]
    },
    "actions":[{
        "name":"Comment",
        "link":"https://www.facebook.com/4681211244366/posts/4681199684077"
    },{
        "name":"Like",
        "link":"https://www.facebook.com/4681211244366/posts/4681199684077"
    }],
    "privacy":{
        "value":""
    },
    "type":"status",
    "status_type":"approved_friend",
    "created_time":"2014-10-11T21:33:29+0000",
    "updated_time":"2014-10-11T21:33:29+0000"
},
...
```

To display data use something like this:

```
<div id='fb-root'>
    <div ng-repeat="post in facebook">
        Post from: {{post.from.name}} <br />
        Story: {{post.story}} <br />
        Tagged: <span ng-repeat="tag in post">{{tag.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should result in something like this:

```
<div id='fb-root'>
    <div>
        Post from: Zachy Bear Jones <br />
        Story: Zachy Bear Jones and Alexander J. Marrs are now friends. <br />
        Tagged: <span>Zachy Bear Jones</span><span>Alexander J. Marrs</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, It is grabbing a post from like a week ago but it is progress thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I can pull one object?  for example, {{tag.picture}} returns a lot of pictures.  Is there a way to do {{tag.picture.1}} or something like that?

Comment: You could try something like <div ng-if="$index == 1">{{tag.picture}}</div> - Don't know if this works. Proper way would be manipulating the whole object in your controller before rendering the data in the view...